# index.js is not found by index.html in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a Cordova android application which I am trying to debug using Chrome developer tools. This application is a modified example application - I think it was Hello Cordova. I have it working on my android device, however I wish to debug in order to develop it further. My problem is that the buttons won't work, because it can't locate index.js even though it is shown in the file tree in chrome. I have tried putting the line  at the end within 'body' but outside the  tags, but this makes no difference. I'm sure I had it working before. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,  maximum-    scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="app">
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<canvas style="width:100%;height:80%;" id="map_canvas">
</canvas>
<label id="stopwatch">00:00:00</label>
<button type=button id="start" onclick="app.myStopwatch.start  ()">Start</button>
<button type=button id="stop" onclick="app.myStopwatch.stop()">Stop</button>
<button type=button id="photo" onclick="app.myStopwatch.photo ()">Photo</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```